# How to deploy flask Rest-API on Azure (taking image as input parameter)

Tags: python, azure, deployment, flask-restful

I've made a flask Rest API that is taking an image as an input parameter (form-data) and then detecting some text from the image and giving back a JSON response. I've tested the API locally using Postman and its working fine.

I want to deploy it to the AZURE, thus, I could be able to call it from mobile apps or other frameworks. there are several tutorials available about how to deploy simple flask API to Azure, but I'm confused about how would be the process when API is taking the image parameter.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any more updates for the question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes I solved it, thank you

Comment: What is the reason you do not accept my answer when it helps you solve the problem?

Comment: I already did! cheers

Comment: If it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

> how would be the process when API is taking the image parameter

If you mean the parameter when you run the docker image with docker command, it just runs the shell command in the container as you designed in the Dockerfile. You can take a look at the docker command [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/). But if you mean the parameter for the REST API of the flask, see the example [here](https://www.roytuts.com/query-parameter-in-rest-api-get-request-with-python-flask/).

And to deploy the image to Azure, there are many ways to do it. You can use the Web App, Container Instance, or use the VM directly and you can do it as you did in your local machine.